# How to reupload a package to PyPI?

Tags: python, package, upload, pypi, http-status-code-400

I upload a package to PyPI, but I got some trouble after upload, so I delete it completely, and I tried to re-upload, but there are some error after upload again:

> HTTP Error 400: This filename has previously been used, you should use a different version.

It seems PyPI can track the upload activity, I delete project and account and upload again, but I can see the previous record. Why?
How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In short, you cannot reupload a distribution with the same name due to stability reasons. Here you can read more about this issue at https://github.com/pypa/packaging-problems/issues/74.

You need to change the distribution's file name, usually done by increasing the version number, and upload it again.

Answer (score 3):

> Yes you can reupload the package with same name.

I had faced similar issue what I did was increased the version number in `setup.py` and delete the folders generated by running `python setup.py sdist` i.e. dist and `your_package_name-egg.info` and again run the commands `python setup.py sdist` to make the package upload ready.

I think `pypi` tracks the repo from folder generated by `sdist` i.e. `dist` and `your_package_name-egg.info` so you have to delete it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running your local pypi server then you can use `-o,--overwrite`  option which will allow overwriting existing package files.

```
pypi-server -p 8080  --overwrite  ~/packages &
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> HTTPError: 400 Bad Request from https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
> This filename has already been used, use a different version. See https://pypi.org/help/#file-name-reuse for more information.

When I tried to upload a package to [PyPI](https://pypi.org/) with the command below:

```
twine upload dist/*
```

So, I changed `version` from `"0.0.1"` to `"0.0.2"` or `name` from `"example_package_superkai"` to `"example_package_hyperkai"` in `pyproject.toml` as shown below, then I removed `dist` folder:

```
# "pyproject.toml"

...
[project]
...
# version = "0.0.1"
version = "0.0.2"
...
```

Or:

```
# "pyproject.toml"

...
[project]
# name = "example_package_superkai"
name = "example_package_hyperkai"
...
```

Then, I ran the command below:

```
python -m build
```

Finally, I could upload a package to `PyPI` with the command below:

```
twine upload dist/*
```